# send SMS Que through api using NODE JS Express JS Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, sms, schedule

I have 500 000 data in a single collection (NODE JS, Express JS, Mongoose).
We need send a sms to each one of them. we have a  direct API URL.

Now we need to send this one by one in the background and update the status on db as sent.

There is a condition, to send 60 sms per minute.
How do i schedule automatically in the background.

How do i send this? Is it possible via corn tab? Any reference

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution is to use a [timer function](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) like `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, run it every minute, fetch a batch of unsent messages from the database and send them while marking them as sent. There are a few caveats:

- Make sure the sending function finishes before being executed again, in case sending the batch of messages takes more than 1 minute. Running `setTimeout` at the end of the function is a safer alternative to `setInterval`.
- Active timer will prevent your application from exiting, so make sure in to run `clearTimeout` in an exit handler.
- Periodic task can block your event loop, so it may be better to either run message sending in a separate [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads) or as a completely separate process (i.e. script executed separately with Node).

Possibly more robust option is to use a job scheduler like [bree](https://github.com/breejs/bree) or a task queue like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) (requires Redis).